# Pandas function for subtract a cumulative column monthly

Tags: python, pandas

I have a weather dataset, it gave me many years of data, as below:

| Date | rainfallInMon |
| --- | --- |
| 2009-01-01 | 0.0 |
| 2009-01-02 | 0.03 |
| 2009-01-03 | 0.05 |
| 2009-01-04 | 0.05 |
| 2009-01-05 | 0.06 |
| ... | ... |
| 2009-01-29 | 0.2 |
| 2009-01-30 | 0.21 |
| 2009-01-31 | 0.21 |
| 2009-02-01 | 0.0 |
| 2009-02-02 | 0.0 |
| ... | ... |

I am trying to get the **daily rainfall**, starting from the end of the month subtracting the previous day. For eg:

| Date | rainfallDaily |
| --- | --- |
| 2009-01-01 | 0.0 |
| 2009-01-02 | 0.03 |
| 2009-01-03 | 0.02 |
| ... | ... |
| 2009-01-29 | 0.01 |
| 2009-01-30 | 0.0 |
| ... | ... |

Thanks for your efforts in advance.

Comment: If you have all days: `df['rainfallDaily'] = df['rainfallInMon'].diff()`

Comment: @mozway it doesn't work well when at the end of the month, it would return a negative number.

Comment: OK, I hadn't seen the data restarted per month, then you need a groupby ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because there is many years of data need [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) for month periods for distinguish `month`s with `year`s separately:

```
df['rainfallDaily'] = (df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.to_period('m'))['rainfallInMon']
                         .diff()
                         .fillna(0))
```

Or use [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html):

```
df['rainfallDaily'] = (df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M',key='Date'))['rainfallInMon']
                          .diff()
                          .fillna(0))
```

---

```
print (df)
        Date  rainfallInMon  rainfallDaily
0 2009-01-01           0.00           0.00
1 2009-01-02           0.03           0.03
2 2009-01-03           0.05           0.02
3 2009-01-04           0.05           0.00
4 2009-01-05           0.06           0.01
5 2009-01-29           0.20           0.14
6 2009-01-30           0.21           0.01
7 2009-01-31           0.21           0.00
8 2009-02-01           0.00           0.00
9 2009-02-02           0.00           0.00
```

Comment: awesome :) - I don't use the `pd.Grouper` class enough looks really handy.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
# Convert to datetime if it's not already the case
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df['rainfallDaily'] = df.resample('M', on='Date')['rainfallInMon'].diff().fillna(0)
print(df)

# Output
        Date  rainfallInMon  rainfallDaily
0 2009-01-01           0.00           0.00
1 2009-01-02           0.03           0.03
2 2009-01-03           0.05           0.02
3 2009-01-04           0.05           0.00
4 2009-01-05           0.06           0.01
5 2009-01-29           0.20           0.14
6 2009-01-30           0.21           0.01
7 2009-01-31           0.21           0.00
8 2009-02-01           0.00           0.00
9 2009-02-02           0.00           0.00
```